# ReactJS handling quantiteis in cart

Tags: reactjs, e-commerce

in an ecommerce project, i made a cart which its functionality can be seen here
[codesandbox.io/s/confident-torvalds-smg72?file=/src/App.js](http://codesandbox.io/s/confident-torvalds-smg72?file=/src/App.js)

my main problem is that, no matter the number i put in the field, the product is incremented only by 1

here's my guess at explaining it

- current value: 1 / I type 4
- onChange is triggered with quantity 4 and previous value 1
- adjustCart run, and loop 3 times
- first time in loop addToCart is run it update the cart and so the value in the quantity field (it is updated to 2) and also the name is updated (with a value like {ID}_2) since the filed changed onChange is triggered again
- this time onChange will have current value=2 and previous_value=2
- so product_to_add=0 and nothing happen

cant find a good solution with a good usability (i can put an update cart button, but i cant handle the onChange with,  since i dont know how many filed i have, i can use a +- solution, but it would be better to put an arbitrary number in fileld and automatically update cart)
if you have suggestions, of any kind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason you're seeing issues is because if you call `setCart`, the value of `cart` doesn't actually update until the next render. So when you call `setCart([...cart])` a second time you are expanding the original version of `cart`

You can get around this by using a function updater, where you pass a function which receives the latest version of `cart` as it's first parameter:

```
setCart((latestCart) => ([...latestCart, ...newCart]);
```

I think you should consider restructuring your `cart` state to better reflect how you are using the data, for example if you used:

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "product 1", qty: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: "product 2", qti: 1 },
]);

// you can update the quantity using one call to setCart:
setCart(cart.map(item => {
    if (item.id === itemIWantToUpdate) {
         return { ...item, qty: newQuantity };
    }
    return item;
}));
```

Comment: Thank you!
i think i will follow the second path, at the beginning i thought it would be useful to store the cart as expandend items (i have a cart badge that simply indicate the cart.length)

Comment: To get the total number of items in the cart you could use `cart.reduce((total, item) => total + item.qty, 0)`

Comment: Thank you already there, its almost working with this conversion, need to fix the decrease (but looks easy), but there is still a thing i dont' like, i cant backspace or delete on the field, not a big deal, but i dont like it that much

Comment: If you can't work it out post up another question with your new code and what the problem is and someone will be able to help :) My guess would be the input events and change handler aren't causing the value of the field to change for some reason, is the `value` prop of the field set correctly?